# Получить hash из div

Tags: javascript

Как получить hash из этого дива?(На JS)

`<div class="item" id="13766679063" zoom="z_d" cost="3434.30" hash="Something" 
   ar="156.54"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hasAttribute(name) – проверяет наличие атрибута

getAttribute(name) – получает значение атрибута

setAttribute(name, value) – устанавливает атрибут

removeAttribute(name) – удаляет атрибут

```
document.getElementById('13766679063').getAttribute('hash')
```

Comment: А есть ли что-то по типу getElementByAttribute?

Comment: @AndrewKasyanov, Таких методов нет, т.к. его роль играет id.

Comment: @AndrewKasyanov да, есть такое `document.querySelector('selector')` только селектор коректныйпередать надо

Comment: Используйте новый стандарт
elem.querySelector('.любое_выражение_css') - тут будет первый найденный элемент (если их несколько)
или 
elem.querySelectorAll('.любое_выражение_css') -  тут будут все элементы. далее работайте с ними через цикл

Answer (score 0):

Версия на jquery:

```js
alert($('.item').attr('hash'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="13766679063" zoom="z_d" cost="3434.30" hash="Something" 
   ar="156.54"></div>
```